# Import Data from Google Sheets into Excel (Using G-Suite)

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets, export-to-excel

I would like to be able to import data from Google Sheets to Excel.

I can currently import data from Google Sheets into Excel, using VBA found (See below)'. However, to achieve this I need to change the 'Share' option on the Google Sheet to 'Anyone with a Link'. Is it possible to still perform the query in VBA, but only change the 'Share' option to 'Anyone in this group with the link can view' as I'm am using Google G-Suite and I do not want to make the Google Sheet Public to the whole world?

```
Sub Import_Sheets_to_Excel()
  Dim QRT As QueryTable, ul As String, ky As String

If ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Count > 0 Then ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).Delete
  ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
  ky = "1ldBURfb1mWJy-BfzHF_zMQawRyXKHUhJkOHvnsWno3o"
  ul = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:html&key=" & ky
  Set QRT = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & ul, _
    Destination:=Range("$A$4"))

With QRT
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
   .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .Refresh
End With

End Sub
```

Have tried the VBA Code (above), but would like to know if there is an alternative solution.